# In an if and only if proof, why do you have to prove sufficiency?

Tags: proof-writing

This my be a simple question and I am missing something fundamental. When doing if and only if proofs, doesn't necessity imply sufficiency, so why does the 'if' have to be proven if the 'only if' is true?

Comment: No, in P iff Q, you need to show that P implies Q and Q implies P both.

Comment: "$A$ if $B$" means "$B\implies A$" (i.e. $A$ is necessary for $B$). "$A$ only if $B$" means "$A\implies B$" (i.e. $A$ is sufficient for $B$) . Therefore, "$A$ if and only if $B$" means "$A\iff B$", i.e. $A$ is necessary and sufficient for $B$.

Comment: Necessity does not imply sufficiency.  Example:  equilateral triangle:  two sides equal is necessary, but not sufficient.

Comment: Besides the examples given, the following "visual" example might help. Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Then "$x \in A$ if $x \in B$" means $B \subseteq A,$ and "$x \in A$ only if $x \in B$" means $A \subseteq B.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necessity certainly does not imply sufficiency. As an example:

The planet Earth existing is *necessary* for a unicorn to exist and live a happy life, as they cannot survive in the vacuum of space.

The planet Earth existing is not *sufficient* for a unicorn to exist and live a happy life, as we can see, unicorns do not exist.